# Concatenate arguments using a loop to form command in shell script

Tags: shell, loops, arguments, concatenation

I've tried different suggestions on this website and elsewhere but nothing has worked. I need to pass some arguments to a shell script and then concatenate them on a string to then launch it as a command. So I do this

```
command="perl perl_script.pl"

for arg
do

command+="$arg "

done

eval $command
```

But I get this error

```
bowtie_script_simple.sh: 43: bowtie_script_simple.sh: comando+=-n : not found
bowtie_script_simple.sh: 43: bowtie_script_simple.sh: comando+=3 : not found
```

According to other threads I've seen that should work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting result because the example code given shows "command" the error shows "comando+=-n" which is not the same.... are you sure this is the exact code that can cause the error?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I wrote it in english here but it's in spanish on my code. But the code is the same, it gives the error

Comment: try command="perl perl_script.pl "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
command="$command $arg"
```

Do your args have (or are likely to have) whitespace ? You should probably quote further for safety's sake.

Comment: Yeah well some arguments go like this -n 3 but I figured shell will read them as separate arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenating as a string introduces difficulties when handling args with spaces. With bash/zsh/ksh, using an array works better:

```
command=(perl perl_script.pl)
for arg; do
    command+=("$arg")
done

# or more simply
# command=(perl perl_script.pl "$@")

# now, execute the command with each arg properly quoted. 
"${command[@]}"
```

From you error message, it looks like you're using /bin/sh -- that shell does not have a `var+=string` construct -- have to use a shell with more features.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
command="perl perl_script.pl"

for arg in $@
do
  command="$command $arg"
done

$command
```